# Suddenly I'm getting "Failed to obtain access token. Authorization Server reports reason: (unknown)" from Facebook

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth

I've been using DotNetOpenAuth 3.5.0.10357 successfully for the last 2 years and TODAY I'm getting "Failed to obtain access token.  Authorization Server reports reason: (unknown)" while processing facebook response.

Any ideas? Has facebook changed something today? Anyone having same issues?

```
public ActionResult FacebookResponse(string returnUrl)
    {
        IAuthorizationState authorization = facebookClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();
        if (authorization == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No authorization from Facebook!");
        }
        else
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
```

Error is on facebookClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();

Thanks

Comment: Please add some of the code you are using to authorize - it's pretty hard to debug anything without seeing the code.

Comment: I'm having exactly same issue today. The app was working for the past year up until yesterday, but this morning we started getting same exception. No changes has been made within last week.

Comment: Could it be this? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/595817690494760/

Comment: Its back working. It was some king of facebook service downtime/temporary bug.